# Bot discord is not returning anything

Tags: discord.py

I am pretty my code is right but it seems the bot isn't working.

I gave it administrator permissions, I am sure i have the right youtube api key and the right token.

In discord when I write - and a word it doesn't send anything back. The bot is online and everything is going on well so I don't think it is an issue with the code

```
import discord
import googleapiclient.discovery
from discord.ext import commands

cmd = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=discord.Intents.all())
token = 'M'
api_service_name = "youtube"
apiversion = "v3"

KEY = ''
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    api_service_name, apiversion, KEY)

@cmd.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.reply(f"You are on cooldown for {round(error.retry_after, 2)} seconds!")


@cmd.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 4, commands.BucketType.user)
async def info(ctx, *args):
    output2 = ''
    for word in args:
        output2 += str(word)
        output2 += ' '
    request3 = youtube.videos().list(
        part="snippet, {} , statistics".format(output2),
        chart="mostPopular",
        regionCode="KR"
    )
    response3 = request3.execute()
    print(response3)
    channame = response3['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
    chanid = response3['items'][0]['id']
    numberViews = response3['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
    numberLikes = response3['items'][0]['statistics']['likeCount']
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title=f"{channame}", url=f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%7Bchanid%7D", color=0xFF5733)
    embed2.add_field(name='Views', value=f"{numberViews}", inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Likes', value=f"{numberLikes}", inline=False)
    await ctx.response.send_message("Hello!")
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed2)

cmd.run("")
```

Comment: What are you doing and what are you expecting to happen? You say "when you right `-` and a word nothing happens" but the code indicates that something will only happen if you do `-info|. When you do that, does something happen? Is there any output at all? The more information about the problem you provide, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: Your error handler at the top swallows all errors so you can't see what's going wrong. Re-raise the exception...

Comment: I tried to type -info vba and nothing happens. I will code different errors handlers and post a message again